# Packer doesn't import project ssh keys (googlecompute)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, packer

Packer seems to exclude ssh keys from the project but I have set the block-project-ssh-keys value to false. The final command fails but that user has an ssh key tied to the project.

Any ideas?

```
{
    "builders": [
      {
        "type": "googlecompute",
        "project_id": "mahamed901",
        "source_image_family": "ubuntu-1804-lts",
        "ssh_username": "packer",
        "zone": "europe-west1-b",
        "preemptible": "true",
        "image_description": "Worker Node for Jenkins (Java + Docker)",
        "disk_type": "pd-ssd",
        "disk_size": "10",
        "metadata": {"block-project-ssh-keys":"false"},
        "image_name": "ubuntu1804-jenkins-docker-{{isotime | clean_image_name}}",
        "image_family": "ubuntu1804-jenkins-worker"
      }
    ],

    "provisioners": [
        {
          "type": "shell",
          "inline": [
            "sudo apt update",
            "#sudo apt upgrade -y",
            "#sudo apt-get install -y git make default-jdk",
            "#curl https://get.docker.com/ | sudo bash",
            "uptime",
            "sudo curl -L \"https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.23.1/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)\" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose",
            "sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose",
            "sleep 5",
            "cat /etc/passwd",
            "#sudo usermod -aG docker jenkins",
            "#sudo docker ps",
            "#rm ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
          ]
        }
      ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is controlled by [metadata](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/googlecompute.html#metadata) option `block-project-ssh-keys` `true` or `false`.

See this [issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/packer/issues/6201)

(the format of your metadata is wrong, remove the square brackets `[ ]`.)

Comment: It's set it the metadata. I marked it with the arrow.

Comment: If you want people to check your code/template, include it in your post as text, not an image link.

Comment: It still doesn't work. Packer still blocks the instance from picking up project keys.  I ran the json file as shown above.